# Count occurrences of a string ocurring in multiple columns at the same time

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
   data_ID   col1   col2
0      001  Word1  Word1
1      002  Word2  Word2
2      003  Word1  Word3
3      004  Word1  Word1
```

I would like to count the number of times `Word1` appear in both `col1` and `col2`. For this dataset, the answer would be 2, since `Word1` appears in both `col1` and `col2` twice.

Answer (score 3):

Just compare with `==` or `.eq()`, and then use `all` across the rows with `axis=1`. That'll a True for each row where `col1` and `col2` are both `Word1`. Then just use `sum`:

```
count = df[['col1', 'col2']].eq('Word1').all(axis=1).sum()
```

Output:

```
>>> count
2
```

If you want to count all the combinations, and easy solution would be to use `value_counts`:

```
all_counts = df[['col1','col2']].value_counts().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> all_counts
    col1   col2  0
0  Word1  Word1  2
1  Word1  Word3  1
2  Word2  Word2  1
```

Or, if you need a mapping, you could make a `MultiIndex` and then use `value_counts`:

```
all_counts = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df[['col1','col2']].to_numpy().T).value_counts()
```

Output:

```
>>> all_counts
(Word1, Word1)    2
(Word2, Word2)    1
(Word1, Word3)    1
dtype: int64

>>> all_counts[('Word1', 'Word1')]
2
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! What if I wanted to count the combinations of all the words possible? For example, I want to count the number of times "word1" and 'word2', appear in both columns.

Comment: How would the output for that be? A mapping of combination to count?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @user check the answer now. Updated :)