# Python count number of occurrences based on other columns (dictionary words)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is an example of my dataframe:

```
text                             name1  name2 name3   count_name
barbie and ken live in a house   barbie ken   sophie  2 
bond is preparing a bond movie   bond   james NaN     2
homer likes donuts               homer  bart  NaN     1
where does mary live             peter  NaN   NaN     0
i am travelling with john        john   NaN   NaN     1
barbie ken barbieken             barbie ken   NaN     2
```

The last column "count_name" shows what I want to obtain. I want to count the number of times each "name1", "name2" and "name3" appear in column "text".
I tried this code following a previous question (which probably would not give me exactly what I wanted) ([Count occurrences of a string ocurring in multiple columns at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71608700/count-occurrences-of-a-string-ocurring-in-multiple-columns-at-the-same-time)):

```
import pandas as pd
df['count_name'] = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df[['text', 'name1', 'name2', 'name3']].to_numpy().T).value_counts()
```

but I obtain a column full of NaNs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a regex:

```
import re

cols = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']
# or
# cols = list(df.filter(regex=r'name\d+'))

pat = df[cols].stack().groupby(level=0).agg('|'.join)

df['count_name'] = [len(re.findall(p, t)) for t, p
                    in zip(df['text'], pat)]
```

To account for full words only:

```
df['count_name'] = [len(re.findall(fr'\b(?:{p})\b', t)) for t, p
                    in zip(df['text'], pat)]
```

Output:

```
                             text   name1  name2   name3  count_name
0  barbie and ken live in a house  barbie    ken  sophie           2
1  bond is preparing a bond movie    bond  james     NaN           2
2              homer likes donuts   homer   bart     NaN           1
3            where does mary live   peter    NaN     NaN           0
4       i am travelling with john    john    NaN     NaN           1
```

If you just want to count the full words, then use a `set`:

```
import re

cols = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']
S = df[cols].agg(set, axis=1)-{np.nan}

df['count_name'] = [sum(1 for w in t.split() if w in s) for t, s
                    in zip(df['text'], S)]
```

Output:

```
                             text   name1  name2   name3  count_name
0  barbie and ken live in a house  barbie    ken  sophie           2
1  bond is preparing a bond movie    bond  james     NaN           2
2              homer likes donuts   homer   bart     NaN           1
3            where does mary live   peter    NaN     NaN           0
4       i am travelling with john    john    NaN     NaN           1
5            barbie ken barbieken  barbie    ken     NaN           2
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
df["count_name_2"] = df.apply(
    lambda row: sum(
        row["text"].count(n) for n in row.filter(regex="^name") if not pd.isna(n)
    ),
    axis=1,
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                             text   name1  name2   name3  count_name  count_name_2
0  barbie and ken live in a house  barbie    ken  sophie           2             2
1  bond is preparing a bond movie    bond  james     NaN           2             2
2              homer likes donuts   homer   bart     NaN           1             1
3            where does mary live   peter    NaN     NaN           0             0
4       i am travelling with john    john    NaN     NaN           1             1
```

---

EDIT: To compare words, you can use `str.split` (I've added `str.lower` as well):

```py
df["count_name_2"] = df.apply(
    lambda row: sum(
        sum(word == n for word in map(str.lower, row["text"].split()))
        for n in row.filter(regex="^name")
        if not pd.isna(n)
    ),
    axis=1,
)

print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I just found a small problem. If I have in the first row "barbie and ken barbieken" it will count 4, when I want to count 2. I should also thought about this when making my question, I will edit it.

Comment: @MGFern I'm a bit surprised that you haven't also tested/commented on the other options. Andrej: the double loop has a quadratic complexity, it's inefficient if you have many columns and many words in the text.

Comment: @MGFern just to be clear, my goal wasn't to  get you to change your accepted answer (choose the one you really like best). I only commented as it's a bit frustrating to spend time to answer and not have feedback ;)

Comment: I obtain the same results with both answers.

Answer (score 0):

There are already some answers, a similar "one-liner" with one regex per text cell.

```
df.apply(lambda row: 
   len(re.findall("|".join(filter(lambda s: not pd.isna(s), 
                   (row[c] for c in row.index if c.startswith("name")))),
                    row.text
       )),
   axis=1
)
```

Note that you run into troubles if you have for example:
`name="Bill"` with `text="Billy"` this will be a false positive match.

An improvement is
 `r"\b" + r"\b|\b".join(...) + "\b"`
to account for word boundaries.